# Filling a matrix with a vector

Tags: python, numpy

I have a huge matrix and am trying to do this:

```
  vec=numpy.zeros(3)
  matrix=matrix.astype(numpy.object)
  matrix.fill(vec.copy())
```

The matrix is filled with vector objects sharing same memory. How to overcome this?

Comment: Why do you need this? Wouldn't 3-dimensional ndarray suit you?

Comment: That will work. Thanks.